# Bugzilla web API for adding a version to a product

Tags: api, continuous-integration, bugzilla

I want my build server to create a version in our Bugzilla tracker every time a release build is made. Is this possible? So far, I've found the following APIs that come close, but don't provide this functionality:

[Bugzilla::WebServer::Product](http://www.bugzilla.org/docs/tip/en/html/api/Bugzilla/WebService/Product.html) - Allows updating of a couple fields from the product, but not the versions.
[Bugzilla REST API](https://wiki.mozilla.org/index.php?title=Bugzilla%3aREST_API%3aMethods&oldid=281673) - Only provides methods dealing with bugs, nothing with the product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will have to create your own API. I'd create a simple Perl CGI that uses the Version package.
http://www.bugzilla.org/docs/4.2/en/html/api/Bugzilla/Version.html

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was afraid of.

Answer (score 0):

There is an existing feature request with a patch out for this: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=777047

Be sure to vote to help push this through.